# Confusion regarding passing arrow notation as argument in function call in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Im having a little bit of trouble understanding a particular concept regarding pointers. I've included code regarding my particular situation below. Here is some of the code in question.

We have a struct that contains a series of structs as members.

```
struct Contact
{
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;



};
```

Now within the main file we have a call to a function defintion which passes the address of the Contact struct to this particular function defintion.

```
 getContact(&contact);
```

With the function defintion being this

```
void getContact(struct Contact* contact) {
    getName(&contact->name);
    getAddress(&contact->address);
    getNumbers(&contact->numbers);

}
```

Now my issue arises here, where Im not sure what exactly is being passed to the GetName or GetAddress functions etc. Now I know that arrow notation gives access to the members of the struct that the pointer "points" to, but im not really sure what is being passed here? My guess is that we are passing the address of the member of the structure that the pointer is pointing to? or is it that we are passing the address of the pointer itself?

This is being passed to this function

```
void getName(struct Name* name)
{


    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", name->firstName); 
    clearKeyboard();
}
```

So I was wondering if someone could explain step by step what is going on or exactly what is being passed especially for when we are passing the arrow notation as a parameter onwards. Im having the most trouble with that. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: "we are passing the address of the member of the structure that the pointer is pointing to". Yes that's it. `contact->name` is the `struct Name` field. So putting an `&` in front of it gives the address of that field.

Comment: Use `()` to avoid your doubts: `getName(&contact->name);`requires guessing or knowledge of operator precedence; `getName(&(contact->name));` is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you! I just had one last question regarding the last part of the process, now that the address has been passed to the GetName function,now  when we access the field firstName through the arrow notation using the pointer *name* (which contains the address of the struct name field) it will update that field "permenantly" since we are doing pass by address.

Comment: `&s->x` is basically just adding an offset to the pointer `s` (and changing its type).  It's equivalent to `&(*s).x`, i.e. `&((*s).x)`.  The new pointer points to a member of the structure, and modifying that member through the new pointer will change that field in the original structure.

Comment: @Yunnosch The first form should be clear to anyone with a passing knowledge of C.  Primary expression are fundamental to the language, and the `.` and `->` and `[]` operators bind more tightly than unary operators.  True, adding the redundant parentheses is "harmless", but it adds clutter and appears unnatural to an experienced C programmer.